# Whats the exact reason of these PMD rule 'Avoid Reassigning '?

Tags: pmd

Reassigning values to incoming parameters is not recommended.  Use temporary local variables instead.

Answer (score 2):

Code clarity. By some, it is considered an ill approach to assign values to parameters within a method's body, as it is, at times, confusing. Some developers prefer always assuming that a parameter is never assigned any value during a method's run.

```java
public class Foo {
    private void foo(String bar) {
        // ...
        bar = "something else";
        // ...
    }
}
```

You expect `bar` to be a value given by the caller, and it is overwritten instead. You can easily rephrase this to avoid pmd warning:

```java
public class Foo {
    private void foo(String bar) {
        String myBar = bar;
        // ...
        myBar = "something else";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Going with this example, wouldn't the better way to respond to the PMD violation be to alter the method signature by removing the 'String bar' parameter completely? If the parameter is simply overwritten and the passed in value is never actually utilized, why make the callers of the method pass in a value at all?

Comment: Maybe the value is used before it gets overwritten. For example, I get a parameter `String bar = "C:/temp"`, I create a directory with this value of `bar` and next I say `bar += "/test.txt"` and I create a file with this new value of `bar`. This way the parameter value is used and later it gets reassigned.

Comment: Oh okay, I agree if the parameter is used before reassignment it should be kept. From the warning Example I could not tell if it was ever used or not. Thanks for clarification.